# Getting an undefined function error building a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm learning to build a chrome extension, and I'm starting with a simple one which will launch a new tab when the icon is clicked, basing the URL of the new tab on the URL of the current one.
In my javascript file, I have the following method:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var newURL = "http://foo.com";
  var numberpatt = new RegExp("\/\d+\/");
  if (numberpatt.test(tab.url) == true) {
    newURL = newURL.concat(numberpatt.exec(tab.url));
  }
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL, "active":true });
});
```

The method is being called when the icon is clicked, and my goal was to append digits from the end of the current URL to the end of "foo.com"

However, I am getting an error on my if-statement that says "Stack trace: TypeError : undefined is not a function", and only foo.com ever launches, without the path.

My manifest is as follows:

```
{
    "name":"My Extension",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "declarativeContent", "tabs"
    ],
    "page_action":  {
        "default_icon":{
            "19": "images/icon19.png",
            "38": "images/icon38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Extension"
    },
    "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: The if statement, `if (numberpatt.test(tab.url) == true)`

Comment: Can `numberpatt` have the function `test` assigned to it?